# "dsconfigad: Invalid credentials supplied for binding to the server" when baking in password

Tags: active-directory, mac

I am using apple remote desktop to try to bind our macs to the AD. Every time I get the error `dsconfigad: Invalid credentials supplied for binding to the server`.

`dsconfigad -add domain.com -computer TESTMAC -username tech -password "Mypass$$-"  -localhome enable -useuncpath disable -groups "Domain Admins, Enterprise Admins" -alldomains enable -mobile enable -mobileconfirm disable`

I know everything in the string is correct and the credentials are right because if I SSH into the machine and run it there without the password baked in, it prompts for the password which I type in and it binds properly.

My only thought is there is something syntactically wrong with the `-password "Mypass$$-"` part, but I am following the `man()` page explicitly.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/dsconfigad.8.html

Answer (score 1):

Solved,

One of the special characters I was using in the password didn't seem to jive well in the command (escape character or something maybe) 
Anyway, I changed the password and all is good now!

Comment: I actually tried with single quotes with no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

The shell performs some interpretation of things in double-quotes, so for example if your password actually contains `$$`, it'll be replaced by the shell's process ID. Actually, if it contains `$`, it'll perform *some* sort of replacement (details depend on what comes after the `$`). Also, backquotes, backslashes, exclamation marks, and probably some other things I'm forgetting will all trigger various sorts of substitution within double-quotes.

Solution: use single-quotes instead. The only thing the shell does in a single-quoted string is look for the close quote, so as long as you don't have a single-quote (aka apostrophe) in your password, `-password 'Mypass$$-'` should work.